# How can I obtain the .dll's from a NuGet package?

Tags: nuget-package, assemblies

I need the .dll's for Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc version 15. How can I obtain them?

It seems that this is distributed as a "NuGet package". Fair enough, but the computer (B) I need it for does not have the means to download it.

I need to obtain the .dll's on my own computer (A) and then transfer them to the other computer (B).